# Why Is WebRTC Blocking Other Applet Applications Which Use Different Ports

Tags: serial-port, port, webrtc, blocking, japplet

The WebRTC is worked on firefox or google chrome.And ı want to ran applet on the same browser too.Namely simultaneously. But the applet can't run because JRE problem.I ran the WebRTC Node Server on 1337 port. But i can't run other applet aplications after i opened the WebRTC application on  port 1337. Why is WebRTC blocking other applications which use different ports. I opened one port (1337) for webRTC. I wonder that the webRTC also use some other ports because of video streaming ? Is WebRTC blocking because of UDP or TCP ? Why is it blocking ? Can't i use applet application which uses port and webRTC application simultaneously. What can i do for this problem?

Comment: on what port range does the applet try and run?

Comment: applet doesn't use port range. Applet application  uses only two port.And webrtc application use one port. More precisely, ı can set in the code.In my opinion web rtc blocked jdk or jre.

Comment: Is the applet accessing the media inputs?(Camera/microphone?)

Comment: I think web rtc use Applet's ports when video stream is continuing.